# Wondering how Arrayadapter work

Tags: android, adapter

All:

Thanks for help. My question is HOW arrayadapter deal with the listarray passed to it, why it does not work after I assign a new arraylist to vlist( Please refer to the code between comment line)? I try to use vlist = new ArrayList(); rather than vlist.clear();  but it just does not work.

```
import .....


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button load;
    ListView content;
    Context context;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    List<String> vlist;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        load = (Button) findViewById(R.id.load);
        content = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.content);
        txtJson = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtjson);
        context = this;
        vlist = new ArrayList<String>();
        load.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                DataLoader dLdr = new DataLoader();
                try {
                    dLdr.execute(new URI("http://someweb:3000/videolist"));
                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, vlist);
        content.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    private class DataLoader extends AsyncTask<URI, Integer, List<String>> {

        ProgressDialog wait = new ProgressDialog(context);

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<String> result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);



/*******************************************************************/
                vlist.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
                    vlist.add(result.get(i));
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

/*******************************************************************/





            wait.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            wait.setTitle("Loading...");
            wait.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected List<String> doInBackground(URI... params) {

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet getter = new HttpGet(params[0]);
            List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

            try {
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(getter);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream is = entity.getContent();
                InputStreamReader isRdr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                BufferedReader bfRdr = new BufferedReader(isRdr);
                StringBuilder strBldr = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;

                while ((line = bfRdr.readLine()) != null) {
                    strBldr.append(line);
                }

                String result = strBldr.toString();

                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray jArray = jObj.getJSONArray("list");
                results = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    results.add((String) jArray.getString(i));
                }

                return results;

            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: you don't really need an ArrayList. you can directly use the methods from ArrayAdapter to add/remove items from the adapter.

Comment: Also, apparently you are in the typical case of `displaying a list of items got from a json webservice`, so i can suggest you to take a look at this article (disclaimer: I wrote it) : http://njzk2.wordpress.com/2013/08/06/json-to-listview/

Comment: @njzk2 Thanks for help, I will read that link, see if I can figure out, but more suggestion and code sample is more than appreciated.

Comment: @njzk2 I read that post, but I have no idea how to tell which item is already exsited in current adapter, so if I use add(T item), there could be plenty of duplicates, how to solve this problem? thanks

Comment: good point. In your code you use `clear` on the arrayList, there is a similar method in arrayAdater.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to create your own adapter where you can set the list.

Check out http://www.piwai.info/android-adapter-good-practices/ for more info.

Comment: @Pieces  Since this is my 1st time try this kinda project, so I just want to start from basic point, could you give me some tips base on current code?

Answer (score 0):

Check out 
 [ArrayAdaptor constructor code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.6_r2/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#ArrayAdapter.%3Cinit%3E%28android.content.Context,int,java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)

You can see the constractor calls

```
Arrays.asList(objects)
```

Which by it self creates a new instance of  ArrayList [see function](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.asList%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29).

Meaning that changing vlist doesn't change the Arraylist that ArrayAdaptor  is using.

The easiest fix would be to call

```
adapter.clear()
adapter.addAll(result) 
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: but why notifydatasetchange() can affect the new created arraylist? In both situations, there should be the same reference, right?

Comment: Nope, because Arrays.asList(objects) returns a new instance. vList and that returned instance do not point to the same reference

Comment: -1. this is incorrect. The code from the OP uses another constructor, which takes an arrayList as parameter, and uses it verbatim.